# simulate isotropic linear diffusion smoothing by python

Tags: python, opencv, smoothing

I want to apply the de-noising filter I named in the title which is based on the following equations:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yAa9.png)

where d = 1 is a scalar constant diffusivity parameter, I(x, y) is the initial noisy image, and u(x, y, t) is the image obtained after a diffusion time t lets say 5, 10 and 30. However, I am quite confused about which function to use and how, in order to achieve this in python?

Here is a sample image:

Comment: See https://scipython.com/book/chapter-7-matplotlib/examples/the-two-dimensional-diffusion-equation/ and perhaps https://sandipanweb.wordpress.com/2017/08/24/diffusion-and-variational-methods-in-image-processing-and-computer-vision/ and http://www.thevisualroom.com/2D_linear_diffusion.html. Search Google to find more references

Comment: @fmw42 thank you, I saw sandipanweb.wordpress.com/2017/08/24/… but I need python code. with an image input. I google it a lot but couldn't find a useful one.

Comment: you won't find python code for that inside opencv. OpenCV is implemented in C++. any opencv function you call, from python or anywhere else, is compiled C++ code.

Comment: @ Christoph Rackwitz for me its important to implement  isotropic linear diffusion smoothing by python